# php get all defined variables in method or function

Tags: php, variables, reflection

In php, how to get all variables defined in a method or function. There is the `get_defined_vars()` function, which gives variables of the function where I am printing(dump). But I need a function which takes a method name as argument and returns all variables in it.

Example: `giveMeAllVariablesDefinedInside($class, $method)` or something like this.

Comment: `get_class_vars($class_name )`?

Comment: Given you can get the information you want to have. What would you like to do with them? Sounds like a XY-Problem.

Comment: I just need data of this variable to use in my future coding. I am going parse my classes and show up.

Comment: Why not just write the data to a property from inside the method?

Comment: @gogagubi did you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

[`get_defined_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

> This function returns a multidimensional array containing a list of all defined variables, be them environment, server or user-defined variables, within the scope that **`get_defined_vars()`** is called.

Comment: No I don't need parameters. I need list of variables defined inside method.